# How to store LocalDateTime in h2 db?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, h2, localdatetime

What is the proper way for storing LocalDate instances in h2 db?

I am using data type `TIMESTAMP` but getting a strange behaviour depending on the `user.timezone` java process started with.

When I insert a `TIMESTAMP` with timeZone America/Toronto - and read it back with timeZone UTC - there will be a 1 hour difference for `2021-05-01` but not for `2021-01-01`.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Make sure you have `h2-1.4.196.jar` in the current folder. Start h2 console with:

```
java -Duser.timezone=America/Toronto -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

For JDBC URL I am using, not all are relevant I assume but `MV_STORE=FALSE` and `MVCC=FALSE` should be important.

```
jdbc:h2:~/mydb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;CACHE_SIZE=16384;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE
```

Run the following query to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (  
   time TIMESTAMP NULL, 
);
```

Insert two rows:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2021-05-01 00:00:00.0')
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00.0')
```

Verify you inserted data successfully, which returns:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
time  
2021-05-01 00:00:00.0
2021-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

Now stop the java process you started and this time run it with the following, note the `user.timezone` is different:

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Console
```

Connect using the same URL above and run the same SELECT query above. Observe the hour difference in the result **only for the first entry.**

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
time  
2021-04-30 23:00:00.0
2021-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: Not sure what's surprising you there - you're storing an instant from the epoch and then printing that instant in different timezones, so they are giving you different results...

Comment: @g00se Why is the difference not 5 hours? Why 1 hour? Time difference between UTC and Toronto is not 1 hour.. TIMESTAMP is not a time with timezone, it is a local date time. The result should be same irrespective of the timezone set.

Comment: Oh right, yes. 2021-05-01 00:00:00.0 and 2021-05-01 04:00:00.0 is what I get for America/Toronto and UTC respectively

Comment: On the 28th of March 2021 at 02:00am time has been forwarded to 03:00am in some countries. This is the somewhat artificial daylight saving performed in many countries of the world (BTW, to be fair it is an achievement of the current Turkish president that Turkey [now Türkiye] is not playing with the tine anymore - his only achievement IMO). As a result the 01.05.2021 00:00 is actually the 30.04.2021 23:00 (BTW both days are national holidays in Vietnam, 30.04.1975 marking the end of that somewhat pointless Vietnam war - Vietnam never played with the time).

Comment: January is in winter, May (more like) in summer ;) (most countries + time zones (except UTC;) have "daylight saving", which is *exactly* 1 hour))

Comment: @xerx593 Exactly :) And +1 for Bruce Lee :)))

Comment: but to answer the title question/that's how good db's/admins do it by default: "db time" should be *always* UTC. (oracle, Sql-server, mysql,...) Crap: http://h2database.com/ is down a.t.m.!?? (but i assume it uses OS/jvm time zone;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the 28th of March 2021 at 02:00am time has been forwarded to 03:00am in some countries. This is the somewhat artificial daylight saving performed in many countries of the world (BTW, to be fair it is an achievement of the current Turkish president that Turkey [now Türkiye] is not playing with the tine anymore - his only achievement IMO). As a result the 01.05.2021 00:00 is actually the 30.04.2021 23:00 (BTW both days are national holidays in Vietnam, 30.04.1975 marking the end of that somewhat pointless Vietnam war - Vietnam never played with the time).

Toronto has daylight savings.

H2 is ignoring user.timezone, I suppose. But not entirely.
Based on xerx593 comments, I agree, it's a bug.

Abolish daylight savings:
https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin?s=20&t=FiPQedQk0YY1ywzPPA6VlA

Answer (score 2):

You're using an entirely outdated and unsupported version of H2 database, even more, you're using a legacy storage backend in it, **PageStore (unlike MVStore) doesn't really support changes in JVM timezone**.

You need to use the default MVStore backend and you also should consider an upgrade, support of JSR-310 Java data types (`java.time.*`) in H2 1.4.196 has various known issues.